# Does the windows key only operate on release?

Tags: buttons, keyboard, standards

I noticed that the windows button only activates when you are no longer pressing down on it. However, I have found no documentation or article to verify that that this is either inherently true, or manufacturing standard.

Comment: What do you mean?  Shortcut keys that use the Windows key as a modifier (e.g. Win+R) work fine while the Windows key is held down.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's by design,windows start menu only pops up when i release the key.And when i use other short cuts like win+R,or win+H,it comes to effects immediately

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, as it's the correct answer.

It's done specifically so the Windows key can be used both as a modifier key like [Ctrl] or [Alt] and a standalone key in it's own right - if the start menu appeared immediately on you pressing down, it would look silly for the menu to be stuck on screen or disappear again when you then pressed another key.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this depends on both the version of the windows operation system that you are using as well as the type of hardware (e.g. laptop or type of keyboard manufacturer).

Something Windows has to cater for is the range of hardware device support (hence the large number of drivers and updates), so even though you might expect a similar behaviour for the Windows button, I don't think it is a surprise that there are variations as well.

On the laptop that I am using right now, tapping the Windows key produces the same result as holding it down and then releasing it (brings up the Windows start menu).